# asp.net gridview Sorting by date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I am sorting my date with my sql query and I get a proper result.

But as I apply

gridview.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
gridview.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

to my gridview. The sorted data gets unsorted.

Comment: You need to perform sort pro-grammatically. because normally in grid value is in string perform

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. You mean to say I should do a custom sort? Can you give any example?  

I have noticed that if I do not apply UseAccessibleHeader and  HeaderRow.TableSection  my data is displayed in sorted format.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.gridviewname.MasterTemplate.EnableSorting = true;

this.RadGridView1.MasterTemplate.EnableSorting = True



SortDescriptor descriptor = new SortDescriptor();
descriptor.PropertyName = "Yourcolumnname";
descriptor.Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
this.gridviewname.MasterTemplate.SortDescriptors.Add(descriptor);



 descriptorcolumnname As New SortDescriptor()
descriptorShipName.PropertyName = "columnname"
descriptorShipName.Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending

try this
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I am not able to get MasterTemplate option with my gridview and even sortdiscriptor is not showing up. I hope you are talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.sortdescriptor(v=vs.91).aspx link.

Comment: k if my code is not properly working then you can use Dataset and store your sorted database values to a dataset .and bind the dataset to your grid view .

Comment: I am doing the same thing. But after binding the data I apply  gridview.UseAccessibleHeader = true; gridview.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; which makes it unsorted again

Comment: if (HeaderRow != null && !AllowPaging)
        {
            UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
           
        }  try to make your code inside a if condition just like this,  and call your function from page load like protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            functionname(arguments);
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which is working fine for me.

-- C# Code here---

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Gridview Property of Sorting</h1>
      <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="gdviewevent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="gdviewevent_Sorting" AllowSorting="true">
             <HeaderStyle BackColor="YellowGreen" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="cambria" ForeColor="Black" />

            <RowStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr No.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span><%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %></span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="India Value" SortExpression="IndiaVal">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblindiavalue" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Column1") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created Date" SortExpression="Registereddate">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="lblcreateddate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Registereddate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
```

-- Page behind Code ---

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                FillGridView();
            }
        }
        protected void FillGridView()
        {
            string query = "Select Column1, Registereddate from tablename";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gdviewevent.DataSource = dt;
                gdviewevent.DataBind();
                ViewState["dirState"] = dt;
                ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";
            }
        }

        protected void gdviewevent_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtrslt = (DataTable)ViewState["dirState"];
            if (dtrslt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortdr"]) == "Asc")
                {
                    dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
                    ViewState["sortdr"] = "Desc";
                }
                else
                {
                    dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Asc";
                    ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";
                }
                gdviewevent.DataSource = dtrslt;
                gdviewevent.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Comment: please explain your solution a bit more